# How to pass idle_in_transaction_session_timeout parameter in db url?

Tags: postgresql, connection, connection-pooling, postgresql-11

How to pass idle_in_transaction_session_timeout in db url ?

When passed as query param in db url along with username,password,ssl=true &  idle_in_transaction_session_timeout =30000. It is not getting reflected when checked DB status using show all.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it as a options parameter.  For example:

```
$ psql "dbname=postgres options='-c idle_in_transaction_session_timeout=77s'"
psql (12.3)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# show idle_in_transaction_session_timeout ;
 idle_in_transaction_session_timeout 
-------------------------------------
 77s
(1 row)
```

Comment: You wanted to pass it in the connection string.  Why can't you use the options parameter I mentioned above?  Isn't that what you asked for?